# Configure Wordpress to receive Paypal IPN notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, paypal

I'm using Wordpress in my Website. I have attached a few plugins for processing purchase content on my website. I use the ***Easy Digital Downloads*** (https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads) plugin for managing sales of digital content and ***Paypal IPN for WordPress*** (https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/) to get transaction details from my Paypal account.

I have to create an account on *sandbox.paypal.com* to test whether all functions are running properly or not. For the management of the plugin *Easy Digital Downloads*, current account and recorded properly. However I did not get a report on the *Paypal IPN for WordPress* plugin. I have entered the URL in the plugin into my Paypal account as an address when the transaction report. However I did not get a report from paypal altogether.

So I think to create their own web pages from scratch without a wordpress plugin and run all functions on top of the PHP script. So, am I better keep using *Wordpress* or rebuild the website from scratch by writing my own script.

If you have a reference about the use of the wordpress plugin, please share it in the comments. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you will need to create a [custom WordPress page](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/) and configure Paypal IPN script to post and get data. on such page you can also add features to store the data on a database, send it by mail, add cron jobs or whatever other [IPN scripts](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples) ...

Also, you need to visit paypal website and [set the ipn link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_bBKXaOZes), then post there the data from your website and configure it to post back to the url of the wordpress site with the page to receive paypal ipn post data...

here is a page [example](http://www.infotuts.com/integrate-paypal-ipn-php/):

```
<?php
class PayPal_IPN{
function infotuts_ipn($im_debut_ipn) {

define('SSL_P_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
 define('SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
 $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 if (!preg_match('/paypal\.com$/', $hostname)) {
 $ipn_status = 'Validation post isn\'t from PayPal';
 if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
 // mail test
 }

return false;
 }

// parse the paypal URL
 $paypal_url = ($_REQUEST['test_ipn'] == 1) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_P_URL;
 $url_parsed = parse_url($paypal_url);

 $post_string = '';
 foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
 $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
 }
 $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
 // get the correct paypal url to post request to
 $paypal_mode_status = $im_debut_ipn; //get_option('im_sabdbox_mode');
 if ($paypal_mode_status == true)
 $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
 else
 $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);

$ipn_response = '';

if (!$fp) {
// could not open the connection. If loggin is on, the error message
// will be in the log.
 $ipn_status = "fsockopen error no. $err_num: $err_str";
 if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
 echo 'fsockopen fail';
 }
 return false;
 } else {
// Post the data back to paypal
 fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
 fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
 fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
 fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
 fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
 fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

// loop through the response from the server and append to variable
 while (!feof($fp)) {
 $ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
 }
 fclose($fp); // close connection
 }

// Invalid IPN transaction. Check the $ipn_status and log for details.
 if (!preg_match("/VERIFIED/s", $ipn_response)) {
 $ipn_status = 'IPN Validation Failed';

if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
 echo 'Validation fail';
 print_r($_REQUEST);
 }
 return false;
 } else {
 $ipn_status = "IPN VERIFIED";
 if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
 echo 'SUCCESS';

 }

return true;
 }
 }
 function ipn_response($request){
 mail("sanjeev00733@gmail.com","My subject",print_r($request,true));
 $im_debut_ipn=true;
 if ($this->infotuts_ipn($im_debut_ipn)) {

 // if paypal sends a response code back let's handle it
 if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
 $sub = 'PayPal IPN Debug Email Main';
 $msg = print_r($request, true);
 $aname = 'infotuts';
 //mail send
 }

// process the membership since paypal gave us a valid +
 $this->insert_data($request);
 }
 }
function issetCheck($post,$key){
if(isset($post[$key])){
$return=$post[$key];
}
else{
$return='';
}
return $return;
}
 function insert_data($request){
 require_once('dbconnect.php');

$post=$request;
$item_name=$this->issetCheck($post,'item_name');
$amount=$this->issetCheck($post,'mc_gross');
$currency=$this->issetCheck($post,'mc_currency');
$payer_email=$this->issetCheck($post,'payer_email');
$first_name=$this->issetCheck($post,'first_name');
$last_name=$this->issetCheck($post,'last_name');
$country=$this->issetCheck($post,'residence_country');
$txn_id=$this->issetCheck($post,'txn_id');
$txn_type=$this->issetCheck($post,'txn_type');
$payment_status=$this->issetCheck($post,'payment_status');
$payment_type=$this->issetCheck($post,'payment_type');
$payer_id=$this->issetCheck($post,'payer_id');
$create_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$payment_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO infotuts_transection_tbl (item_name,payer_email,first_name,last_name,amount,currency,country,txn_id,txn_type,payer_id,payment_status,payment_type,create_date,payment_date)
VALUES ('$item_name','$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$amount','$currency','$country','$txn_id','$txn_type','$payer_id','$payment_status','$payment_type','$create_date','$payment_date')");
mysqli_close($con);

 }
 }
 $obj = New PayPal_IPN();
 $obj->ipn_response($_REQUEST);

 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. so by using the above script I no longer need to install a plugin "Paypal IPN for Wordpress" ? I using it now,

Comment: The plugin must be using something like this, use it without a plugin or, you can edit the plugin source files according to those settings with WordPress codex. first set the IPN url via PayPal and then try...